# compressing numpy array with zlib + base64 [python]

Tags: python, base64, zlib

I'm trying to send a numpy array through the python `requests` module to a flask server.

First, I compressed the numpy array with zlib, then used `base64` to encode the data, then tried to decode and decompress but it's not working.

```
import numpy as np 
import base64
import zlib
import requests

frame = np.random.randint(0,255,(5,5,3)) # dummy rgb image
# compress
data = zlib.compress(frame)
print('compressed')
print(data)
print(len(data))
print(type(data))

data = base64.b64encode(frame)
print('b64 encoded')
print(data)
print(len(data))
print(type(data))

data = base64.b64decode(data)
print('b64 decoded')
print(data)
print(len(data))
print(type(data))

data = zlib.decompress(data)
print('b64 decoded')
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data = base64.b64encode(frame)` should be

`b64encode (data)`

You’re accidentally encoding the wrong thing ...

Answer (score 0):

I just realized after considering the extra length for base64 encoded string, I can completely get rid of it.

So, the following code snippet does what I need, it compresses the `numpy` array, then I can get the original array back without using `base64`. It gets rid of some of the overhead.

```
import numpy as np 
import base64
import zlib
import requests

frame = np.random.randint(0,255,(5,5,3)) # dummy rgb image
# compress
data = zlib.compress(frame)
print('compressed')
print(data)
print(len(data))
print(type(data))


data = zlib.decompress(data)
print('b64 decoded')


data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8)

print(data)
print(type(data))
```